# Trying to click continue button on paypal with Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

Button: before

[image: Button: before]

Button: After

[image: Button: after]

I've tried many ways to get this working. here's what I have

```
mainagree = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='payment-submit-btn']"))
)
mainagree.click()
print('clicked')
```

I've tried locating it with ID and xpath, both won't click.
I did a bit research on iframe,

but I don't think that particular button is under any iframe.
I am really lost on this one.

Comment: Your xpath is correct. Please check again whether button is under any iframe or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744684/cant-click-a-button-in-selenium), let's try two different approaches for syncing and clicking the button:

`agree_ctn_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'modal-foreground-container')]//div[contains(@class, 'CheckoutButton_buttonWrapper')]//button[@id='payment-submit-btn']"))) driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", agree_ctn_button) driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", agree_ctn_button)`

OR

`agree_ctn_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'modal-foreground-container')]//div[contains(@class, 'CheckoutButton_buttonWrapper')]//button[@id='payment-submit-btn']"))) driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('payment-submit-btn').click()")`

Do either of these code snippets work?

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the reply. I am sorry that I didn't clip everything in that picture when I first made the post. I've edited the post and included both "before" and "after" button. That paypal button shows up as "continue" at first which I can click on the webpage but will not direct me to the next page, then it changes to "Agree & Continue" which is when it's clickable. It doesn't use"disabled" button attribute, but use "data-disabled" as an indication whether the button is clickable or not. I also tried your code, and no luck. Sorry for the inaccurate pictures.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, that makes more sense; this button also switches from disabled to enabled but in a different manner.

`agree_ctn_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'modal-foreground-container')]//div[contains(@class, 'CheckoutButton_buttonWrapper')]//button[@id='payment-submit-btn' and @data-disabled='false']")))`  
  
Can you try the code above? Hopefully we can wait for the element to appear with an XPath specifying that the `data-disabled` property is set to `false` before we interact/click it.

Comment: I should definitely double check everything before I make the post, This works! Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
mainagree = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='payment-submit-btn']"))
)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", mainagree)
```

Try the following out to click on the mainagree button. If it's in an iframe you'd get NosuchElement error.

Comment: This should work as it uses Javascript Executor to perform the click, but the button is still not clicked when I run this.

Comment: Is the button disabled by other fields.

Comment: sorry about the wrong picture. It did use data-disabled as a disabled indication. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Execution screenshot]

As per the given url By you I tried below xpath for Agree and continue and  Selenium clicks it with click method. No Switch to frame or Javascript click is required.

```
//button[@type='submit'][contains(.,'Agree & Continue')]
```

Comment: instead of driver.switch_to.frame(iframez) , can you try 1st driver.switch_to.frame(0)

Comment: Also can you paste the html pls instead of pasting the image so that I can try myselft

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&token=EC-9RB42051WT568412U&rcache=1

Comment: i dont get why execute_script wont work in this case

Comment: i get "agree and continue" button. Is that the button you are referring to?

Comment: yah, agree & continue

Comment: Hi @ShiO, I have used below xpath for Agree and continue button   and its clicking with click method. No switch to frame wor java script click is required. //button[@type='submit'][contains(.,'Agree & Continue')]

Comment: Hi, thank you again for the reply. I tried your way and it still didn't click. Though I tried an abs xpath and it worked with normal click.(), instead of javascript one. Much appreciate the help!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you.Just check if you can get a relative xpath..Absolute xpath is fine for now but in future  any change in DOM structure you would need to change again the xpath .