# Can't click a button in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This is the paypal button!

[image]

I am trying to click a button that goes from disabled to enabled.
It also showed up disabled in its button attribute.

```
<button class="button_E6SE9 primary_1oCqK continue-to-review regular_1jnnf" type="submit" data-automation="review-order" xpath="1"><span class="content_3Dbgg" tabindex="-1">Continue</span></button>
```

[image]

It changes from:

```
<button disabled class> to <button class>
```

So, I am thinking of waiting for the attribute changing and then click the button using to_be_clickable

```
continuebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until
(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Continue')]")).click()
print("clicked")
```

It printed clicked meaning the above step is executed, but the "continue" button on the page is not clicked. I had it worked before, however, I edited that code a few times and now I couldn't get it fixed.

Comment: Try `"//span[contains(text(),'Continue')]/parent::button"`

Comment: Hi, It prints clicked, but does not do anything. I will add a picture

Comment: Is it inside iframe?

Comment: hi, again. I don think it's inisde an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this element is giving you some trouble...

Can you wait until the element is clickable using Selenium but use JavaScript to click the button? Does this work?

```
driver.execute_script("var continue_button = document.querySelector('button.continue-to-review'); continue_button.click()")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Could you also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029037/trying-to-click-continue-button-on-paypal-with-selenium-in-python I posted this question, i tried the same thing for this button and it works half of the time. is there a way to click this button with your method? thank you

Comment: By implementing  wait until and to_be_clickable with the javascript click. Should I simply just add `continuebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until
(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Continue')]")))` this line before the javascript code?  and how can I implement this javascript code with different buttons? Thank you, appreciate the help

Comment: Hi, again. This works with almost every button including the button from my previous question post! I just don't know how I can implement the wait until the button is clickable . my previous wait, until ones don't work.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad it works for your other question and other buttons as well. For the syncing/waiting until we're ready, we may have to get creative:

`continuebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='cost-sum-section']//button[contains(@class, 'continue-to-review') and not(@disabled)]")))`

Does the code above work? This approach is one way to do it... we can wait for the button using an XPath specifying **without** a disabled property present on the button before we proceed to click it with the JS execution.

Comment: you are crazy good, this is the first time i got it to work throughout this month. It works!

Comment: Hi, again. Sorry I have one last question. This is about the question post that I linked in the first comment. I used to be able to click the paypal continue button but only half of the time. I was told I had to scroll down to make the button visible or sometimes I have to add a manual time.sleep delay for it to work. Unlike my previous code that clicks the button half of time. your way `driver.execute_script("var continue_button = document.querySelector('button.ppvx_btn___5-8-2'); continue_button.click()")` works all the time. I am wondering if the wait, until could work in this case?

Comment: I've added the picture of that button in the post.  I never made this fully work, I tried the javascript click and the scrolldown thing in the previous answers that I got. None of them really works. I used to be able to click the button half of the time, your way of clicking works everytime, but I have to manually add the time.sleep delay. I tried`continuebtnv1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='ShipTo_container_2wZjT']//button[contains(@class, 'ppvx_btn___5-8-2') and not(@disabled)]"))) ` but no luck. Thank you for the help

Comment: @ShiO I've added an answer on your other thread here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029037/trying-to-click-continue-button-on-paypal-with-selenium-in-python/

Let's continue to discussion on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
```

if you want be sure if it clicked correct you should use if like this:

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click():
   print('Clicked!')
else:
   print('Element Not Found!')
```

I hope I could help you

Comment: Hi, It prints clicked, but does not do anything. I will add a picture

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, but hard to test without seeing a link.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="button_E6SE9 primary_1oCqK continue-to-review regular_1jnnf" and not(@disabled)]')))
```

Also, try using

```
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[disabled][class*='continue-to-review']")))
```

And click this button with a locator above or any other shorter locator.

Comment: Hi, it printed clicked, but did not actually click the button

Comment: Will it print clicked if you use `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((SelectBy.XPATH, '//button[@class="button_E6SE9 primary_1oCqK continue-to-review regular_1jnnf" and (@disabled)]')))`?

Comment: yea, it printed clicked with your code: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="button_E6SE9 primary_1oCqK continue-to-review regular_1jnnf" and not(@disabled)]')))

Comment: locator in comment is without `not`. But instead of SelectBy use By.

Comment: Hi, again. Sorry for the wrong message. I noticed the change but it somehow pasted the old one. I tested it and it gave a timeout error.

Comment: Is locator with `not` unique? Check in devtools